# Remove or Secure Webhook from Azure Webjob on public web

Tags: azure, security, azure-webjobs, network-security

Whenever an Azure webjob is created a webhook is also created along with it that if used can be used to trigger that webjob. The webjob in question is triggered on a timer and has no need for a webhook. Can this web-hook be disabled ?

Concern: If this URL is available on the public web, someone will try to call this or worse brute force this method of triggering the webjob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a couple of ways of doing it

1. Add Access Restrictions directly on the resource. This is specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions?toc=/azure/azure-functions/toc.json#blocking-a-single-ip-address).
2. Add the resource in a vNet (requires a premium plan) and apply the restrictions there.

Note: To add a Deny All rule, you need to create at least one custom rule and Azure will add the Deny All rule automatically (see link above for details)

Answer (score 0):

We can also **secure webhook API with Azure AD authentication**. To enable Azure AD authentication for webhook API, we need to follow the below steps:

1.Go to you azure app service and click `Authentication / Authorization` to enable it.

[image]

2.In Azure Active Directory provider, choose `Advanced` and put the `webhook API` as `Issuer Url`.

[image]

3.Go to your app service `Access Control`, select `Contributor` role for the service principal you created before.

For more details about secure webhook API you could refer to this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5272246/Secure-Azure-WebJob-API-with-Azure-AD-Authenticati).

Comment: I don't think this is a solution for multiple reasons 1. This assumes that you are using one of the specified IDPs (Custom OIDC provider is in preview at the moment) 2. This sets it for your whole web-app. You might not want that. 3. This provides an authentication context to the url access (remember the webhook urls are already having a credential assocated with them). -- What is needed is a mechanism for noone to be able to access these urls from outside PERIOD.